# Get the inner text using curl concept in php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

This is html text in the website, i want to grab

> 1,000 Places To See Before You Die

```
<ul class="listings">
<li>
<a href="http://watchseries.eu/serie/1,000_places_to_see_before_you_die" title="1,000 Places To See Before You Die">
1,000 Places To See Before You Die
<span class="epnum">2009</span>
</a>
</li>
```

I used the code like this

```
foreach($html->find('ul.listings li a') as $e)
echo $e->innertext. '<br/>';
```

The output i am getting is like

```
 999: Whats Your Emergency<span class="epnum">2012</span>
```

including the span pls help me this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags()` for that

```
echo trim(strip_tags($e->innertext));
```

Or try to use `preg_replace()` to remove unwanted tag and its content

```
echo preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/span[^>]*>/', '', $e->innertext);
```

Comment: no use problem not solved using this echo trim(strip_tags($e->innertext));

Comment: try to use the second example

Comment: @MateiMihai I'm pretty sure the person who gived you -1 is because you should NEVER use regex against HTML. It's a bad suggestion. Maybe now it works but tomorrow he will come back.

Answer (score 4):

Why not `DOMDocument` and get title attribute?:

```
$string = '<ul class="listings">
<li>
<a href="http://watchseries.eu/serie/1,000_places_to_see_before_you_die" title="1,000 Places To See Before You Die">
1,000 Places To See Before You Die
<span class="epnum">2009</span>
</a>
</li>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$text = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="listings"]/li/a/@title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $text;
```

or

```
$text = explode("\n", trim($xpath->query('//ul[@class="listings"]/li/a')->item(0)->nodeValue));
echo $text[0];
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/c94U41mf)

Comment: This is indeed the clean way of doing it. It's a shame that noobs cannot appreciate a good answer. +1 anyway.

Comment: Yes that's true :). I would have given him the answer to `simple-html-dom` but that is not the correct way to parse an HTML as it's a custom library. And moreover to use regex on HTML is totally bad.

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer instead of the one with the regex parsing.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways that I could think of to solve this. One, is that you grab the title attribute from the anchor tag. Of course, not everyone set up a title attribute for the anchor tag and the value of the attribute could be different if they want to fill it that way. The other solution is that, you get the `innertext` attribute and then replace every child of the anchor tag with an empty value.

So, either do this

```
$e->title;
```

or this

```
$text = $e->innertext;
foreach ($e->children() as $child)
{
    $text = str_replace($child, '', $text);
}
```

Though, it might be a good idea to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead for this.

Answer (score -1):

First of all check your html. Now it is like

```
  $string = '<ul class="listings">
               <li>
                  <a href="http://watchseries.eu/serie/1,000_places_to_see_before_you_die" title="1,000 Places To See Before You Die">
 1,000 Places To See Before You Die
                    <span class="epnum">2009</span>
                 </a>
             </li>';
```

There is no close tag for ul, perhaps you missed it.

```
  $string = '<ul class="listings">
               <li>
                  <a href="http://watchseries.eu/serie/1,000_places_to_see_before_you_die" title="1,000 Places To See Before You Die">
 1,000 Places To See Before You Die
                    <span class="epnum">2009</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
            </ul>';
```

Try like this

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
 echo $xml->li->a['title'];
```

Comment: Did you test this code ?? THis would generate `Entity: line 7: parser error : Premature end of data in tag ul line 1`

Answer (score -1):

Use `plaintext` instead.

```
echo $e->plaintext;
```

But still the year will be present which you can trim off using regexp.

Example from the documentation [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

```
$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>");
$e = $html->find("div", 0);

echo $e->tag; // Returns: " div"
echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"
echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"
echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"
```