# Grab the values from some url using curl concept

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the inner text using curl concept in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615733/get-the-inner-text-using-curl-concept-in-php)

code is like this so on ....

```
     <ul class="listings">
        <li>
        <a href="../episode/a_bit_of_fry_and_laurie_s1_e1-106555.html">
        <span class="">Episode 1</span>
        <span class="epnum">13/01/1989</span>
        </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

By means of curl concept i am grabbing the links at **span**
    Episode 1
        13/01/1989
I have used like this

```
foreach($html->find('ul.listings li a span') as $e)
$e->innertext;
```

But my values are getting like

**Episode 1   Taste of Tokyo08/01/2002**,I want only this 
 **Episode 1   Taste of Tokyo**

Comment: I gave an example how it looks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using the simpleHtmlDom

There's the manual :

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

As the selector , if you want fetch the first element

```
// Find all <li> in <ul> 
foreach($html->find('ul') as $ul) 
{
       foreach($ul->find('li') as $li) 
       {
             // do something...
       }
}
// Find first <li> in first <ul> 
$e = $html->find('ul', 0)->find('li', 0);
```